# move imageView permanently in relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I can move my imageView by animations but after moving the onclick method doesn't work.
If I clicked the old default position of the imageview the onClick method is invoked so how can I move the imageView permanently and the listeners work correct?

my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* Remove title bar from transparent activity */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Define Views */
        final ImageView keyboardIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardIcon);
        final ImageView micIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.micIcon);
        final RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        final Animation moveMicIconRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_right);
        final Animation moveKeyIconLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_left);

        micIcon.startAnimation(moveMicIconRight);
        keyboardIcon.startAnimation(moveKeyIconLeft);

        /* OnClick Listeners */
        RL.setOnClickListener(this);
        keyboardIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        micIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        /*-----------------*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.activity_main:
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.keyboardIcon:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "keyboard icon",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case R.id.micIcon:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mic icon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectAnimator was the correct way to completely move the imageview